# Unable to build my first Android program

Tags: android, eclipse, java

I am using,

> Version: Helios Service Release 2
>
> Build id: 20110218-0911

When I try to run the project1 I get the following error.

```
'Lauching project1' has encountered a problem.
Errors occured during the build.

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'project1'.
sun.security.x509.X500Name.
```

Can someone guide me on to resolve this issue?

Regards,
Subbu

Comment: Update you ADT please, and then check.. Are you facing any other error/s?

Comment: you could change the JRE settings in the preference page. Go to Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. Point it to the Sun JDK (Sun JRE might work but I used JDK). Then restart the workbench. Restarting seems to be the key.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem, because I use IBM JRE first time.  Then I re-install all of them by follow up the installing guide order:
Install Sun JDK firstly, then install SDK manager and make sure it find Sun JDK location, then install Eclipse Classic,etc.

Comment: Could you share me installation guide document?

Answer (score 1):

user671253 pointed to a solution that worked for me. That is, installing the Oracle JDK 7u11, and then pointing Eclipse to its JRE :

*Go to Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. Point it to the Sun JDK (Sun JRE might work but I used JDK). Then restart the workbench.*

Comment: It is my pleasure to be of help, regards!

Answer (score -1):

i would recommend getting the "eclipse classic" and installing android plugin to it instead of trying using the eclipse Java EE and other versions. Eclipse seems to break if too many plugings are loaded, that my experiance with android in eclipse.